# USB devices not regconized

Tags: usb, devices

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. When I mount a USB flash drive, my laptop does not recognise those devices. Can you help me to solve this problem?
`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b091 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Webcam
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 7614:1236
```

If you need more details just ask :( 
sorry but i really new in ubuntu >"< give me some specific details please... thanks

Comment: Is there any solution to this question?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a problem with the drive, or the partition/MBR is messed up.

After you plug it in, enter this in the terminal:

`dmesg | tail`

what does it say?  Usually from the error message you can tell what the problem is.

Comment: Also: `while true; do sudo dmesg -c; sleep 1; done`, and repeat plug-in/remove the USB device.

Comment: But then you only have 1 second after it clears to type `dmesg` again so you can save it.

Comment: Could you rephrase that? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: If you paste that loop in, every 1 second, the kernel ring buffer [dmesg] will be cleared.  Once you type in the sudo password once, it doesn't require it for the rest of the session.  So there, the loop is erasing the log messages every second, you have to type in `dmesg` in another terminal at just the right time or it will be blank.  Do you get it now?